# Ubuntu changing clock adjustment on Windows 10 in dual-boot system

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, timezone

I got a dual boot desktop with both Ubuntu 18.04LTS and Windows 10. My Win10 time zone and hh:mm settings are automatically synchronized with the server. Somehow, whenever I boot into Ubuntu it does get the time correctly but when i switch back to Win 10 the time settings are messed up. "It adds" 4 hours to my clock. I have tried helplessly setting win 10 to manual time config. I've been wondering if Ubuntu somehow messes with CMOS clock config.

Comment: What time zone are you in? There is the choice in linux to have the cmos hold the time in UTC or localtime, with UTC being preferred. If you live in a region which adjusts the clock twice a year then there are periods when you don't know the time when you boot if the cmos is in localtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended solution from experience is to set Windows to use UTC.

There are two ways to keep the computer clock in sync with the "real world" time.

- One is the default for Windows: the local time.
  That means that the hardware clock is set to 2:00 PM (in New York) even if the world coordinated time is (almost equal to UTC) is 6:00 PM.
  That means that any program (disk files for example) that requires a stable time has to translate the local time to universal every time it is used.
- The other is to keep the hardware clock at UTC time. That is what Unix/Linux do.
  That means that the time to present the user needs to be translated into local time, but that is just a "presentation" layer. The internal time is kept static at any place on earth that the computer is being used. A localtime file is adjusted to display the local time (if needed).

Both Linux and Windows (with some limitations) could use either.

Please read [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_time) for the details. To change Windows time, just change an administrator register key.

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation" /v RealTimeIsUniversal /d 1 /t REG_QWORD /f
```

Comment: It worked. No time conflicts now.